# Undefined method add_column when booting rails server in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-activerecord, heroku-postgres

I'm getting this weird error: `undefined method 'add_column' for #<Class:0x007f7a6a73cf30> (NoMethodError)` when I try to run rails s in heroku. It seems to be throwing this error in the following migration:

```
class AddPresentationAttributesToPosts < ActiveRecord::Base
  add_column :presentations, :ticker, :string
  add_column :presentations, :action, :string
  add_column :presentations, :thesis, :string
  add_column :presentations, :slideshare_url, :string
end
```

However, all of this works locally and `heroku run rake db:migrate` also works without throwing an error. Any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a migration, you should inherit from the `ActiveRecord::Migration`. And don't forget about `up`, `down` and `change` method:

```
class AddPresentationAttributesToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :presentations, :ticker, :string
    add_column :presentations, :action, :string
    add_column :presentations, :thesis, :string
    add_column :presentations, :slideshare_url, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Whoops that's embarrassing. Looks like I accidentally generated models instead of migrations. Thanks!